# Flutter: Failed assertion : 'builder != null home != null

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm a newbie to flutter and working on `StatelessWidget`, what is going wrong with the code, Simply creating MaterialApp but showing error

> Failed assertion : 'builder != null home != null

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "Farhana naaz ansari",
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red
      ) ,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to provide a widget for your `home` property on your MaterialApp widget.

Answer (score 1):

MaterialApp mast have a home, MaterialApp wraps all you app and I added Scaffold Because it wraps you current page, `home: Text("This is the app")` will also work but it no recommended.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Farhana naaz ansari",
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.red
      ) ,
      home: Scaffold(body: Text("This is the app"),),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must set the home to something.
Let say you have homescreen as home.dart with some code.

**Home.dart**

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child : Text("Home")
    );
  }
}
```

Now you must set home to be Home() in your code.

```
import './home.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "Farhana naaz ansari",
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red
      ) ,
      home: Home()
    );
  }
}
```

If no **home** is assigned in material app then it assigns **null** which is causing error in your case. Hope it  helped:)